# Find the max of a convex function in fewest samples

Tags: algorithms

Suppose there is a convex function, and a certain domain interval.  I want to find the max of this function within the interval.  The goal is to minimize the number of times the function is evaluated, because evaluating it is expensive.

I can think of a naive solution involving evaluating the function at two points of the interval (thereby partitioning the interval into three sub-intervals) and discarding the edge sub-interval of the point with the lower function value.  But, I am not sure whether it's optimal.

Comment: It depends on the function, if the curvature of the function is complicated, for any solution you find, one can come up with a function with curvature complicated enough yet still convex and you will not be able to make a guarantee on the number of samples needed to attain the maxima.

Comment: Wrong, the above comment is for finding a minima in convex function OR finding maxima in concave function. As stated above, this question can be trivially answered as some one has below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the function $f$ is convex, its maximum value in interval $[a,b]$ is either $f(a)$ or $f(b)$.  Otherwise, it will violate [Jensen's inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality).

Comment: Uhh ohh, you are right. I misremember convex and concave.

Comment: Dammit, thanks, but I actually meant I have a concave function.  I will close this question and ask another one.  Thanks.

Comment: Sure.  I could be helpful in the concave version, hopefully.  BTW, I think it's better to present the question as find the minimum of a convex function.  And there should be some pre-existing tools.